# change image in a div every 5 seconds in an angular application

Tags: html, css, angular

Hi I am building an angular application and as part of it, I want to change the image in a div every 5 seconds.

Current code

```
 <div class="outer_div">
     <img class="ahu_icon" src="../../assets/image1.png">
 </div>
```

I have a different image - image2.png. I want to display these 2 images one after another every 5 seconds. Can someone help with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an observable that emits the values with a 5 second [delay()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html) for each value by using [concatMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html), and then [repeat()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/repeat.html).

```js
this.src$ = of('../../assets/image1.png','../../assets/image2.png').pipe(
   concatMap(url => of(url).pipe(delay(5000))),
   repeat()
);
```

```html
<img class="ahu_icon" [attr.src]="src$ | async">
```

Comment: @cvg yes, the answer is for Angular 2+.